# Xamarin Forms Custom Navigation Transitions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am aware that this question has been asked before but most of them are from over a year ago and I am wondering whether the issue still persists.

Does Xamarin Forms still provide no support on custom navigation page transitions?

I know that you can make animations well in the native applications but it seems from my research that Xamarin Forms requires either a custom renderer or package for doing a simple custom page transition. Has this changed at all or is that still the norm? Hoping they added some form of support since those threads were asked.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK until recently this was not supported by xamarin forms. Alexandr Nikulin has written a component that can do this however ; https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Forms doesn't have the capability to do that, but there's a workaround.

If you disable the animation transition when Pushing or Popping pages, you can do your custom animation before/after the transition.

Like so:

```
// First animate the opacity of the current page
new Animation(opacity => page.Opacity = opacity / 100, 100, 0)
    .Commit(this, "PageExitAnimation", 1, 350, Easing.CubicInOut, (d, b) =>
    {
         var otherPage = new OtherPage() { Opacity = 0 }; // Create the page with 0 opacity to animate later
         NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(otherPage, false); // Push the new page, as the current page is already with 0 opacity, without animation
         otherPage.FadeTo(1, 350, Easing.CubicInOut); // Animate the fade of the next page
    }
```

You can apply this concept to do any kind of animation, just instead of modifying the opacity, modify the TranslationY, TranslationX, etc. And if you want a complex animation, you can modify more than one at the same time too, just take your time to learn Xamarin.Forms animation and you're good to go :)

Hope that helps! :D

Comment: I don't think so... But it's pretty simple, instead of just calling `PushAsync`, call the code that I wrote on the answer. You can wrap this code in a separate method and call this method instead of `PushAsync` too. Take your time and understand what the code does, then adapt to a `PopAsync` method. It should be pretty simple too, as the only thing that changes is that you'll want to change the opacity before calling `PopAsync` (instead of after when calling `PushAsync`. But if you are developing for Android and iOS only, you can use a plugin that was mentioned as a comment. Hope this helps :)